# I want to create inner shadow shader like in photoshop

Tags: shader, shadow

i want to recreate photoshop effect named "inner shadow" as texture shader . As a start point i've took "outline" example, but i dont know what to do next, or how to create it. Please can somebody share some code example or can help to modify this shader to get inner shadow effect?

```
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
uniform vec3 u_outlineColor;
uniform float u_threshold;
uniform float u_radius;

void main()
{
    float radius = u_radius;
    vec4 accum = vec4(0.0);
    vec4 normal = vec4(0.0);

    normal = texture2D(CC_Texture0, vec2(v_texCoord.x, v_texCoord.y));

    accum += texture2D(CC_Texture0, vec2(v_texCoord.x - radius, v_texCoord.y - radius));
    accum += texture2D(CC_Texture0, vec2(v_texCoord.x + radius, v_texCoord.y - radius));
    accum += texture2D(CC_Texture0, vec2(v_texCoord.x + radius, v_texCoord.y + radius));
    accum += texture2D(CC_Texture0, vec2(v_texCoord.x - radius, v_texCoord.y + radius));

    accum *= u_threshold;
    accum.rgb =  u_outlineColor * accum.a;
    accum.a = 0.0;

    normal = ( accum * (1.0 - normal.a)) + (normal * normal.a);

    gl_FragColor = v_fragmentColor * normal;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Please have take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) a look at how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better feeling for what is on-topic here. As of now, there is no question in your post at all, thus, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: Sorry, can you help me with some code examples to create inner shadow shader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to compute [distance transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform) of your image. The best way is to use [jump flooding](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.101.8568&rep=rep1&type=pdf) algorithm.

[image: Jump Flooding]

1) Specify the significant pixels, for example with step function.

```
        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            return step( _Threshold, tex2D( _MainTex, i.uv ).a );
        }
```

2) Render the seed image for jump flooding algorithm. In seed image encode (0,0) for significant pixels and actual UV position for insignificant ones (at the image above, RG encodes U and BA encodes V with 16 bit precision).

```
        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            return lerp(
                fixed4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ),
                fixed4( EncodeFloatRG( i.uv.x ), EncodeFloatRG( i.uv.y ) ),                 
                1.0 - step( 0.01, tex2D( _MainTex, i.uv ).r )
            );        
        }
```

3-10) Jump flooding steps. At each step you have to iterate over "neighbour" pixels and find which one contains encoded UV position, closest to the UV position of current pixel. Jump flooding must start with farthest "neighbours" and then gradually narrow search distance.

```
        void JumpFlooding(half2 uv, half2 duv, inout half2 nearestPos, inout half nearestDist)
        {
            fixed4 seed = tex2D( _MainTex, uv + duv * _MainTex_TexelSize.xy );
            half2 pos = half2( DecodeFloatRG( seed.xy ), DecodeFloatRG( seed.zw ) );
            if( length(pos) > 0.0 )
            {
                half dist = distance( uv, pos );
                if( dist < nearestDist )
                {
                    nearestDist = dist;
                    nearestPos = pos;
                }
            }
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            half2 nearestPos = half2( 0, 0 );
            half nearestDist = 2.0;

            JumpFlooding( i.uv, half2( -_Offset, -_Offset ), nearestPos, nearestDist );
            JumpFlooding( i.uv, half2( -_Offset, 0 ), nearestPos, nearestDist );
            JumpFlooding( i.uv, half2( -_Offset, _Offset ), nearestPos, nearestDist );
            JumpFlooding( i.uv, half2( 0, _Offset ), nearestPos, nearestDist );
            JumpFlooding( i.uv, half2( _Offset, _Offset ), nearestPos, nearestDist );
            JumpFlooding( i.uv, half2( _Offset, 0 ), nearestPos, nearestDist );
            JumpFlooding( i.uv, half2( _Offset, -_Offset ), nearestPos, nearestDist );
            JumpFlooding( i.uv, half2( 0, -_Offset ), nearestPos, nearestDist );
            JumpFlooding( i.uv, half2( 0, 0 ), nearestPos, nearestDist );

            return fixed4( EncodeFloatRG( nearestPos.x ), EncodeFloatRG( nearestPos.y ) );
        }
```

11) Finally, the last result of jump flooding algorithm encoded to distance field.

```
        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 seed = tex2D( _MainTex, i.uv );
            half2 pos = half2( DecodeFloatRG( seed.xy ), DecodeFloatRG( seed.zw ) );
            float dist = distance( i.uv, pos );                 
            return EncodeFloatRGBA( dist );
        }
```

And now you can use distance field to draw inner shadow.

[image: Inner shadow]

```
        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            half4 color = _ShadowColor;

            half dist = DecodeFloatRGBA( tex2D(_DistTex, i.uv) );

            color.a *= ( 1.0 - smoothstep( _ShadowMinRange, _ShadowMaxRange, dist ) );

            return color;                          
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understand this example. Is this is unity shader? I see 11 step here, can i apply them in one shader script? or i need sequentially store it to some temporary file? do you have working sample to see it real?

Comment: Yep, basically, this is multi-step technique. But, its multi-stepness is because of that distance transform. Still, you might perform distance transform some other way, for example using Photoshop or another image editor.

Comment: Im really sorry, but I can't reproduce it in unity (steps 3-11). Can you help me with working example?

Comment: I know this is a bit old thread, but can someone help me understand what this '_Offset' value is in the 3-10) stage? I am unsure as to what the value needs to be. Would really appreciate the help